# F# Partially apply the second argument

Tags: f#, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

in F# if I take a function that takes two arguments, for example, mod (%):

```
13 % 10
// val it : int = 3
```

which is the same as

```
(%) 13 10
// val it : int = 3
```

is there any way to write it in the pipe notation, currying the 13?

Obviously, the “two-argument function” is actually a one-argument function that returns an intermediate function. So can pipe

```
10 |> (%) 13
// val it : int = 3
```

However, I need the other way around, i.e. pipe the first argument 13, having the second argument 10 partially applied, but not the first one.

Is there anything in the language that helps to do that, without creating extra lambdas every time, i.e. to avoid the following?

```
13 |> (fun x -> x % 10)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911096/how-do-you-curry-the-2nd-or-3rd-4th-parameter-in-f-or-any-functional-la

Comment: Right, but is there any way to reverse the order of partial application without creating extra functions every time, i.e. without let mod10, without (fun x -> x % 10)

Comment: This might just be a typo (well, at more than one place), but I still want to point out that `(%) 10 13 = 10`. So the order of the arguments does not change between prefix and infix form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in, standard way to do this. Moreover, due to how function application works, it's impossible to do so: as soon as you write `(%) 13`, you've already applied the first argument, because function application has the highest and non-configurable precedence in F#.

You can, if course, make yourself a special function to produce a "weird" function application - one that would apply the second argument and leave a hole for the first:

```
let ap f x = fun y -> f y x
```

And then:

```
let x = 13 |> ap (%) 10
> x : int = 3
```

Incidentally, the function `ap` is a semi-standard occurrence in ML languages, and is usually called `flip`, because what it does is "flipping" the order of the arguments:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

Or, you can even make it into an operator:

```
let (-*-) = flip
```

And then:

```
let x = 13 |> (%) -*- 10
> x : int = 3
```

However, this sort of trickery gets unreadable very quickly. In practice, it is far more preferable to just declare a function that does what you need:

```
let mod10 x = x % 10
```

And then:

```
let x = 13 |> mod10
```

Or, if you really need it to be very general:

```
let mod' x y = y % x
```

And then:

```
let x = 13 |> mod' 10
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a combinator that will do this for any function of two arguments:

```
let inline flip f y x = f x y
```

This can be used as:

```
13 |> flip (%) 10
```

Answer (score 2):

F# already contains an operator that will do what you want, namely `<|`:

```
10 |> (%) <| 13;;
val it : int = 10
```

This is equivalent to

```
(10 |> (%)) 13;;
val it : int = 10
```

Comment: It's close, but not exactly whats needed
[11;12;13] |> Seq.map ((%) <| 10);; expected: [1;2;3] actual: [10;10;10]

Answer (score 1):

K, you are looking for a flip

```
let flip f a b = f b a
```

Comment: let mod10 x =
    x % 10 is pretty much the same as (fun x -> x % 10), isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, are you asking for a flipping operator, identity function or something along those lines?
http://techneilogy.blogspot.com/2010/06/flip-operator-for-f.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's the one, yes, "flip".